# Loop through assets field on detail/product page

Tags: assets, plugin-craftcommerce, loop

I am trying to loop through an assets field called `gallery` on entries in a commerce `products` channel.

This field can have multiple images in it. I can get this to work on a channel listing page `domain.com/shop/` but can't get this to work on the entry detail page `domain.com/shop/products/detail/`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
{% for asset in product.gallery.first() %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I edited your question just to clarify some of the naming - the `gallery` field is on entries in a commerce products channel.

Answer (score 3):

`product.gallery` returns an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), which you can think of as a list of elements. `product.gallery.first()` will return the [first](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#first) element in this list.

What you want is to loop over all the elements:

```
{% for asset in product.gallery %}
  <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

(Note that this will work if there are no elements in the list (because the for loop will never be entered). One thing you should avoid doing is `product.gallery.first().url`, because it is **never** possible to be certain without checking that there *is* a first element in the list.)